# Upgrading to Mule runtime 3.9.5 from 3.9.1

Tags: mule, mulesoft

So there are a lot of gaps about this task (earlier staff who were handling upgrades have left and this task has landed in my plate).

We currently use Mule 3.9.1 EE runtime ( standalone EE not CE )
So when i login to MuleSoft and lookup downloads :
[image]

Here is where I am confused ...
Our scripts ( Dockerfile ) are referring to a amazon s3 bucket which is a http endpoint and is accessible by all which does not sound correct to me.

So I am strongly suspecting that this may have been done as a hack to bypass the Dockerfile script from authenticating against MuleSoft's website :
i.e. ( we have access to MuleSoft support so maybe we have downloaded the runtime and then hosted it on a public s3 bucket) and then referred to this s3 location to download the same.

This to me just does not seem correct... I am wondering how others in the world go about it?

Another option i can think of is downloading the Mule runtime from MuleSoft download page and then uploading to our private artifactory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload a propietary product like Mule EE to a public repository you are most likely in violation of the license. You should take it down immediately.